# C strcopy in Python using Ctypes

Tags: python

I wrote this code not expecting it to work:

```
clib = cdll.msvcrt
string = "Hello"
clib.strcpy(string, "WURT")
print(string)
```

It printed out:

```
"Hello"
```

Made sense to me. Python strings are objects after all, so I decide to do what I thought would be the correct implementation:

```
clib = cdll.msvcrt
string = c_wchar_p("")
clib.strcpy(string,"Hello")
print(string)
```

It prints out "H," and I scratched my head and said what the...? Any idea why it's only copying a single letter?

Comment: `string` is a Python module, probably better to avoid using it as a variable name.

Comment: Same behavior with any other name I chose, and string isn't in my current global namespace, but thanks for making me aware. :P